# WebRTC H264 connection - strange profile-level-id

Tags: webrtc, h.264, rtsp, v4l2, janus-gateway

I'm trying to establish WebRTC connection between an RTSP camera and a browser.
The cam creates a nice h264 stream which plays well in VLC player.
For WebRTC I'm using [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/).

The camera stream is not playing in either Chrome, either FF, because it offers a strange profile-level-id: ffffc028.

If I force Janus to offer a well-known profile-level-id (which is obviously a hack!), Chrome could play the stream but FF crashes immediately after the first keyframe reception.

Camera stream is created by [v4l2rtspserver](https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver).

### Please help me to identify where this profile-level-id.

Is it valid at all?

Comment: No, it's not valid.

Comment: you might want to file a firefox bug, crashing is bad either way.

Comment: Crash actually happens only on the current window, so FF keeps opened. It just displays that the open h264 has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can / should be able to decode pretty much any H264 stream via WebRTC, encoded with any profile-level, so the issue seems to be with Firefox's H264 decoder. Forcing well-known profile-level-id is the right thing to do, from my experience; this is just WebRTC formalism. The decoder figures correct profile-level from the actual H264 bytestream. Make sure you configure your encoder to attach correct SPS-PPS nalus to every key frame.

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any comparison of the profile level ids and browser compatibility? Which profile level id is the most popular among the browsers? Even when forcing, Chrome usually runs to error, and FF is not playing either. I'll update this with the sps and pps when I get back to the details.

Comment: profile-level-id=42e01f must be implemented by all browsers.